# Using YQL to perform a Google Search

Tags: search-engine, yql, google-search

I am looking to perform a Google Search using the [google.search open table](http://y.ahoo.it/fDRftxuF). Regardless of the query term there are no results. I have also looked at the source code which uses http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0 to perform the Google Search- but using this URL in the YQL console returns in a suspected bot error.

Any clues on how to use YQL to perform Google searches would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may want to look at `google.customsearch` instead. You will need an API key though.

http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/customsearch/v1/getting_started.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for something using Google's index. So not really a custom search for my website...unless you know of a way to make custom search work for the entire web?

Comment: Look at this thread: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2712386 it seems you can do that with custom search.